# How to join texts in an array of dictionaries where one of the kay-value pairs are equal in JS/React without changing the order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, string, dictionary

I have data like this:

```
Record= [ { "tid":1, token_text": "Canis", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" }, { "tid":2, "token_text": "Familiaris", "spanid": 1, "label": "Name" }, { "tid":3, "token_text": "is" }, { "tid":4, "token_text": "the" }, { "tid":5, "token_text": "scientific" }, { "tid":6, "token_text": "name" }, { "tid":7, "token_text": "of" }, { "tid":8, "token_text": "dog", "spanid": 2, "label": "species" }, { "tid": 9, "token_text": "." }]
```

I want to create another array of dictionaries like the data where the token_text strings that have the same spanid are joined and the tid and label_name can be the same as that of the first occurrence. I want to do this while keeping the order of the elements in the array the same as that of the Record array.
I want to do this in JS/ React.
I will appreciate any leads in this matter.
The output will look like the following:

Record = [ { tid: 1, token_text: "Canis Familiaris", spanid: 1, label: "Name" }, { tid: 3, token_text: "is" }, { tid: 4, token_text: "the" }, { "tid":5, "token_text": "scientific" }, { "tid":6, "token_text": "name" }, { "tid":7, "token_text": "of" }, { "tid":8, "token_text": "dog", "spanid": 2, "label": "species" }, { "tid": 9, "token_text": "." }]

I tried objectArray.reduce but the order of the instances in the array is messed up. It orders the elements by their spanid but I don't wanna change the order. I want to keep the order the same as that in the Record array where the elements are ordered by tid.

Answer (score 1):

will first create an empty object called `groupedRecords`. Then, it will iterate through the `Record` array and, for each record, it will check if the record's `spanid` already exists in the `groupedRecords` object. If it does, the code will add the record's `token_text` to the existing record's token_text property. If the record's `spanid` does not exist in the `groupedRecords` object, the code will create a new record with the record's `token_text`, `tid`, and `label` properties and add it to the groupedRecords object.

Finally, the code will log the `groupedRecords` object.

```
  const setOrignalSort = (records, newRecords) => {
    const result = [];
    for (let record of records) {
      const newRecord = newRecords.filter((item) => item.tid === record.tid);
      if (newRecord.length > 0) result.push(newRecord[0]);
    }
    return result;
  };
  
  const Record = [
    { tid: 1, token_text: "Canis", spanid: 1, label: "Name" },
    { tid: 2, token_text: "Familiaris", spanid: 1, label: "Name" },
    { tid: 3, token_text: "is" },
    { tid: 4, token_text: "the" },
    { tid: 5, token_text: "scientific" },
    { tid: 6, token_text: "name" },
    { tid: 7, token_text: "of" },
    { tid: 8, token_text: "dog", spanid: 2, label: "species" },
    { tid: 9, token_text: "." },
  ];

  const joinedRecords = Record.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const spanid = cur.spanid;
    const token_text = cur.token_text;

    if (spanid !== undefined) {
      if (!acc[spanid]) {
        acc[spanid] = {
          tid: cur.tid,
          token_text: token_text,
          label: cur.label,
        };
      } else {
        acc[spanid].token_text += " " + token_text;
      }
    } else {
      acc[cur.tid] = cur;
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

  const sortedJoinedRecords = setOrignalSort(Record, joinedRecords);

  console.log(sortedJoinedRecords);
```

**Edit:**
`setOrignalSort` function will reset the original sort of the `Records` array.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it does not produce the desired results. console.log shows that the instances without the token_text are also clubbed together and for all cases label and tid are undefined. The entries that have spanids will only have labels and others don't. The order will be same like 
Record = [
    { tid: 1, token_text: "Canis Familiaris", spanid: 1, label: "Name" },
    { tid: 3, token_text: "is" },
    { tid: 4, token_text: "the" }, ......]
Please let me know if you have a solution for this.

Comment: I have also edited the question and have included a sample of the output data that I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is it must to be in the same order or can sort it after the reduce function?

Comment: Thanks for the updates! Spanid is missing in the console though. It must be in the same order as that of the initial data and only the consecutive token_text with the same spanid should be merged and the tid and label_name can be the first instance occurring with that specific spanid. Any additions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: now after the join, it will reset the original sort.

Comment: hope you find it useful.